# Storing gene expression data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have m x n matrices of gene expression data that I want to store in MySQL so that searches can be possible using PHP programming.

m is approx 100000 samples (uniquely identifiable)
n is approx 23,300 genes   (uniquely identifiable)

I created three tables as below

```
CREATE TABLE genes (
    `gene_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `gene_name` varchar(99) not null
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE samples (
    `sample_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `sample_name` varchar(99) not null
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE gene_sample (
    `gene_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `sample_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `Expression_value` INT ,
    FOREIGN KEY(`gene_id`) REFERENCES genes (`gene_id`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`sample_id`) REFERENCES sample (`sample_id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Problem is how i insert values in third table(gene_sample) from mXn matric?

how i can store expression values corresponding to sample and genes in gene_sample table?

Comment: What is the source/logic behind the combinations of genes and samples?  Do you want to store _all_ possible combinations, or something else?

Comment: for a single sample there are 23k genes .And these combinations need to store so that queries for searching genes and samples be possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: yes i want to store all possible combinations.

Comment: OK, what is the source of the expression values?

Comment: I have a matric in which expression values are(row wise samples and column wise genes).

Comment: Nice, but do you have a SQL _table_ with the values contained in this matrix?

Comment: No i do not have  SQL table ,i have CSV file for this .

Comment: You might want to mention that in the question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `genes` and `samples` tables already be populated, and you want to populate the `gene_sample` junction table using all possible combinations, you may try using an insert with a cross join:

```
INSERT INTO gene_sample (gene_id, sample_id)
SELECT g.gene_id, s.sample_id
FROM genes g
CROSS JOIN samples s;
```

Of course, this would not assign any value to the `Expression_value` column.  But ideally this column does not even belong in a junction table anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot .then where  i can store expression values ? Do i need more tables?

Comment: You could store the values, assuming they are all unique for each gene and sample.  It depends on your data.  And note that my answer doesn't populate the expression values, because your question does not mention them appearing in any table.

Comment: but sir , this is my problem ,how i can store expression values corresponding to sample and genes ?